# 404 error page in aps.net MVC maintaining the error url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to do a 404 error page in asp.net **(not .net core and I don't have a startup.cs file)**.

I have already did it using .aspx in the webconfig, but as I have to use razor modules, I can't stay with this.

My objective is to keep the wrong url, so I can capture it at google analytics.

When I use responseredirect at customerrors in webconfig, and point it to the cshtml view,
I got the "aspxerrorpath" at the url followed by the wrong path, but I want the url to stay the way I typed.

ex: http://localhost/error?aspxerrorpath=/adadasd

the way I want : http://localhost/adadasd

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can point to a cshtml file directly as they are part of the MVC pipeline, therefore, need a controller. In order to keep the URL the same, you can just use  `<customErrors mode="On" />` and handle errors in the Global.asax Application_Error method where you can Server.Transfer to an error controller route where you can render a cshtml view.

Global.asax

```cs
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    
    // Default error code in case we have nothing more specific to work with
    int errorStatusCode = 500;
    
    if (exception is HttpException httpException)
    {
        errorStatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
    }
    
    // Rewrite the request URL to invoke the ErrorController
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    Response.Clear();
    Server.ClearError();
    
    Server.TransferRequest("~/error/" + errorStatusCode, false);
}
```

Error Controller Action:

```cs
[Route("{statusCode}")]
public ActionResult Index(int statusCode)
{
    if (statusCode <= 0)
    {
        statusCode = 404;
    }

    Response.StatusCode = statusCode;

    return View(statusCode);
}
```